# Saving a file in excel in a location on the computer HD using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, macos, save

I would like to make this code save the image name from a value in a cell. For example if "cat" was in the cell Y36 I would like it to be called cat.jpg.

The code below works when I don't have `& FileNumber &` in it or `FileNumber = Range("Y36")`.

```
Sub ExportCellsAsPicture()


    FileNumber = Range("Y36")

    Const FName As String = "HD:Users:User:Desktop:" & FileNumber & ".jpg"


    Dim pic_rng As Range
    Dim ShTemp As Worksheet
    Dim ChTemp As Chart
    Dim PicTemp As Picture


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set pic_rng = Worksheets("QR Code").Range("Y50:AS70") 'Set your range here
    Set ShTemp = Worksheets.Add
    Charts.Add
    ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=ShTemp.Name
    Set ChTemp = ActiveChart
    pic_rng.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
    ChTemp.Paste
    Set PicTemp = Selection
    With ChTemp.Parent
        .Width = PicTemp.Width + 10
        .Height = PicTemp.Height + 10
    End With

    ChTemp.Export Filename:="HD:Users:User:Desktop:" & FileNumber & ".jpg", FilterName:="jpg"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ShTemp.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

UPDATE: WORKING CODE

```
Sub whatsup()

Dim pic_rng As Range
Dim ShTemp As Worksheet
Dim ChTemp As Chart
Dim PicTemp As Picture
Dim fileCon As String

fileCon = "JK"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set pic_rng = Worksheets("QR Code").Range("Y50:AS70") 'Set your range here
Set ShTemp = Worksheets.Add
Charts.Add
ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=ShTemp.Name
Set ChTemp = ActiveChart
pic_rng.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
ChTemp.Paste
Set PicTemp = Selection
With ChTemp.Parent
.Width = PicTemp.Width + 8
.Height = PicTemp.Height + 8
End With


    'Here I want the .jpg to be called test_yyyy_mm_dd.jpg


ChTemp.Export Filename:="HD:Users:User1:Desktop:" & fileCon & ".jpg"
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ShTemp.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What sheet is `Range("Y36")` on? (can you see its value when it gets to the export line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the Const to a variable. By Definition, a Const(ant) can't change, but you are using it like a variable. Change it to these two lines:

```
Dim FName As String 
FName = "HD:Users:User:Desktop:" & FileNumber & ".jpg"
```

You should also declare FileNumber before you set it.

```
Dim FileNumber As Long 'if this is a number. If not, string
FileNumber = Range("Y36")
```

And finally, it is always good to make everything Explicit and compile to be sure at least your syntax is correct. This will help reduce many simple but easy to miss errors. Place this at the very top of your module:

```
Option Explicit
```

Then compile and correct any syntax errors before debugging.

To debug, set a breakpoint on your first executable line (not a Dim statement) and step through line by line checking to see if it is working as you expect.

Comment: I which order do I add the lines above? Do I need to change anything else, expect for delete 'FileNumber = Range("Y36")

    Const FName As String = "HD:Users:User:Desktop:" & FileNumber & ".jpg"'

Comment: It does not matter as long as your declares (Dim statements) come before you set values, and you set them before you use them. I would put both Dim statements with your other ones and move the value setting lines below those. First set FileNumber because it's used to set FName.

Comment: I have done that, but nothing happens! Not even an error... I think I may have made a mistake elsewhere, do you think you can write the edits into my code?

Comment: So your next step is to debug. Set a breakpoint on the "FileNumber = " line and then step through line by line checking the values as you go to see if they are what you expect.

Comment: I have updated the code and now works, will post it for others in the box above.